# contact form 7 not working in popup functionality using by different short-code

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

when using multiple popup functionality in same page with different form from contact form 7, getting one form in all popup. The popup done by magnific popup or any other popup plugin supported by contact form. how it will solve?

Comment: post your sample code here

Answer (score 2):

I have made multiple contact forms with popup & it's working fine in my side.

I have used [Popup Maker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/) plugin for setting multiple forms in Popup.

1) Install the Plugin first.

2) Then go to Popup Maker section & add new popup with title & contact form 7 shortcode.

3) There is Trigger section inside Popup Maker page. You can set Trigger on click with define class name there & use it that class name in button to open it in popup.

If you have any doubts then follow the guide from plugin page which I have given.

You can create multiple Popup this way with multiple contact form 7 shortcode.

I hope this will be useful for you.

Thanks.